# How to add '/' character in JSON array?

Tags: java, json

I want to add a string that contains the value `"1/07/2013 10:23:21 AM"` into a JSON object; when I put it into the json object I found it as `"1\/07\/2013 10:23:21 AM"`. the JSON object I use is a request JSON of a WS call. So I need it as exactly. Any way of help will be thankful!

Comment: The JSON parser at the WS end should deal with this. Doesn't it?

Comment: \ is just a escape sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Don't care about that, to type "/" the system must type an escape character, in tihs case "\", and the another extreme must decode it properly.

so 2013/07/25 is, in RAW code "2013\/07\/25".